Find the solution to a system of inequalities
The problem goes like this:
$c,d$ are positive numbers and they satisfy:
$$c+d<1,$$
$$c>d,$$
$$c<2d,$$
$$c>\frac12.$$
Does there exist $a,b>0$, such that all of the following are satisfied：
$$ac+bd<1,$$
$$(a-1)c+(b-1)d>0,$$
$$5ac+\frac32bd<2c\,\text{?}$$

This is hard to read.  Please edit for clarity.  In particular, please explain the connection with viscosity.

It is confusing to have 1. and then $5ac+1.5bd$. It looks like $1.5ac+1.5bd$. You could use fractions to clarify your formulas.
